# Firewall port is out of range

Tags: c#

code should be correct, but when I run it, it says port value is out of range (I tried "6" or "1433", which I need). Anyone know what is wrong?

```
try
{
    INetFwRule firewallRule = (INetFwRule)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FWRule"));
    firewallRule.Action = NET_FW_ACTION_.NET_FW_ACTION_ALLOW;
    firewallRule.Description = rule.Text;
    firewallRule.Enabled = true;
    firewallRule.InterfaceTypes = "All";
    firewallRule.Name = rule.Text;

    firewallRule.LocalPorts = port.Text;
    firewallRule.Protocol = (int)NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_.NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ANY;

    INetFwPolicy2 firewallPolicy = (INetFwPolicy2)Activator.CreateInstance(
    Type.GetTypeFromProgID("HNetCfg.FwPolicy2"));
    firewallPolicy.Rules.Add(firewallRule);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
}
```

Comment: This may be the result of using `NET_FW_IP_PROTOCOL_ANY` - since not all protocols have the concept of a port it's probably invalid to specify a port at all in that case. Try a specific protocol like TCP or UDP as appropriate.

Comment: Problem solved, thank you!